# How can I check if all the elements in a list are the same?

Tags: python, list

There is a list, whose items are either integers or string `NULL`. How can I check if the list is all `NULL`, without checking each item in the list using a loop?

Answer (score 4):

Convert the list to a set and compare it like this

```
>>> set(["NULL", "NULL"]) == {"NULL"}
True
>>> set(["NULL", "NULL", 1]) == {"NULL"}
False
```

When you convert your list to a `set`, all the duplicates are removed and only the unique values are retained. Now, you can compare it against another set with just `NULL`. They both are equal, then your actual list has only `NULL`s.

**Note:** Converting to `set` will only work if all the items in your list are hashable. In your case, you have only numbers and strings. So, you are fine here.

---

Alternate, and the idiomatic, way would be to use `all` function (or its sister function `any`)

```
>>> all(item == "NULL" for item in ["NULL", "NULL", 1])
False
>>> all(item == "NULL" for item in ["NULL", "NULL"])
True
```

Here, if the non `NULL` value is somewhere in the middle, then `all` will immediately return `False` and you don't have to check the entire list. Similarly, `any` can be used with `not` like this

```
>>> not any(item != "NULL" for item in ["NULL", "NULL", 1])
False
>>> not any(item != "NULL" for item in ["NULL", "NULL"])
True
```

Comment: (Of course this also checks all the items in the list, using an implicit loop)

Comment: @Tim: But are the implicit loop and an explicit loop similarly efficient?

Comment: @Tim: The implicit loop is faster since it's implemented in C.

Comment: @Tim: If you expect the list to generally be all NULL, use the `set` approach. But if the list is likely to contain integers, the `any` / `all` approaches may be faster, especially if the integers are early in the list.